# Regex: match only routes with or w/o GET params EXCEPT containing the 24 bytes HEX string

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I wanna create 2 separate handlers for 2 routes below, first will do collections' actions, second - document related things. Two regex are needed for that.

That pattern

```
^\/api\/([\w]+)\/([\w]+)(\/([a-f0-9]{24}))?\/?\??.*$
```

covers all two cases

1)

```
/api/appslug/collectionname
/api/appslug/collectionname/
/api/appslug/collectionname?key=val
/api/appslug/collectionname/?key=val
/api/appslug/collectionname?key=val&hello=there
/api/appslug/collectionname/?key=val&hello=there
```

2)

```
/api/appslug/collectionname/5919a81f318139c5157636f9
/api/appslug/collectionname/5919a81f318139c5157636f9/
/api/appslug/collectionname/5919a81f318139c5157636f9?key=val
/api/appslug/collectionname/5919a81f318139c5157636f9/?key=val
/api/appslug/collectionname/5919a81f318139c5157636f9?key=val&hello=there
/api/appslug/collectionname/5919a81f318139c5157636f9/?key=val&hello=there
```

How to create separate pattern for routes containing mongo id ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want this regex: `^\/api\/\w+\/\w+\/[a-f0-9]{24}(?:[\/?].*)?$` ?

Answer (score 1):

The optional `(\/([a-f0-9]{24}))?` is responsible for that `/5919a81f318139c5157636f9` part. Remove it from for collections (and also require the question mark to be mandatory if parameters exit to distinguish them from document ID):

```
^\/api\/([\w]+)\/([\w]+)(?:\/?\?.*|\/)?$
```

(demo: https://regex101.com/r/WEoEA5/1)

and make it mandatory for documents:

```
^\/api\/([\w]+)\/([\w]+)\/([a-f0-9]{24})\/?\??.*$
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but unfortunately your first pattern covers all two cases.

Comment: actually, i can place ^\/api\/([\w]+)\/([\w]+)\/([a-f0-9]{24})\/?\??.*$ that route pattern before the second and it will work well, but i wanna get another solution.

Comment: @Xitroff: yes, you're right. I forgot to make `?` mandatory. Please see the updated answer.